# Error when trying to get apps permissions

Tags: android

I'm trying to get app's permissions but I get compile error **"Cannot resolve requestedPermissions"**
 . Tried using it as method and symbol. 
 [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skh5s.png)

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            try {
                for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : applist) {
                    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
                    String[] requestedPermissions = applicationInfo.requestedPermissions;
                    if (requestedPermissions != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
                            Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            listadapter = new AppAdapter(ViewAppsPermissions.this, R.layout.list_item, applist);

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I get compile error

Comment: Use  requestedPermissions is not method. Use .requestedPermissions();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ApplicationInfo` does not have a `requestedPermissions` field. [`PackageInfo` does](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions). Change:

```
String[] requestedPermissions = applicationInfo.requestedPermissions;
```

to:

```
String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `requestedPermissions` is not a method, it is a field within the `PackageInfo` class.  You should reference it like this:

`String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;`

Answer (score 0):

String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;